# How do I know how many more defenders are there in a city?

Tags: civilization-6

I've encountered something pretty bizarre in Civilization 6. It could even be a bug.

I surrounded a city with a really large number of archers. I pounded the city until **both the progress bars at the top of the city turned empty**.

All attacks on the city now show "**Total city damage**" as the predicted outcome of the battle before I launch the attack.

[image: Total City Damage]

Yet, despite hitting the city with **10+ attacks every turn** and **each attack killing a defender**, there still seem to be more defenders inside the city.

[image: Defender ties each attack]

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't take a city with ranged units, so they are probably just wasting their attacks at this point.

Cities do also heal (about 10 to 20 points a turn) each turn so in between your attacks the city is probably recovering.

You'll need to bring a non ranged unit in to make an attack, at which point they should take the city.

Comment: ^ the city will never really have 0 defense. Just take it with a melee unit and they'll be fine.